# nested progress tasks into one progressbar javafx

Tags: javafx, task

Is it possible to render in one progressbar the progress of 2 nested tasks?
I mean, if I have to read lines from several files in several directories. I have this snippet code:

**EDIT:**

```
final int steps = directories.size();
    Task<Integer> task2 = new Task<Integer>() {

                /**
                 */
                @Override
                protected Integer call() throws Exception {

                    int len = files.length;
                    updateProgress(0, len);

                    for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        final String filename = files[i].getName();
                        final String file = files[i].getPath();     

                        try {
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                            }

                            String currentLine = null;

                            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                                readlines(currentLine, filename);
                            }

                        } catch (IOException xs) {
                            xs.getMessage();
                        } 

                        System.out.println("******* Working on: " + file +  " ******************************");
                        updateProgress(i + 1, files.length);
                    }   

                    System.out.println("done: " + directoryName);

                    return len;
                }
            };  

    task2.setOnRunning(r -> {
                DoubleBinding totalProgress = null;

                for(int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {    
                    DoubleBinding increment = task2.progressProperty().divide(steps);

                    if (totalProgress == null) {
                        totalProgress = increment;
                    } else {
                        totalProgress = totalProgress.add(increment);
                    }
                }

                progressBar.progressProperty().bind(totalProgress);
                status.textProperty().bind(task2.stateProperty().asString());
                statusProcess.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when(totalProgress.isEqualTo(-1))
                        .then("0.00")
                        .otherwise(task2.progressProperty().multiply(100.00).asString("%.02f %%")));

                console.textProperty().bind(task2.messageProperty());

            });

    new Thread(task2).start();
```

I am enable to access progress bar but as long as I have directories, the progress bar will restart to 0 and will check for files into the next directory and then populate the progress bar until 1 and then restart to 0 if there is another directory.

How can I do if I want to display these 2 tasks in one as I don't want to restart from 0 when the next directory is reading. If I have for example 4 directories, I expect to see a moving the progressbar until its quarter and so on.

Is anybody as an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
progressBar.progressProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
    () -> Math.max(0, task1.getProgress()) / 2 + Math.max(0, task2.getProgress()) /2 ,
    task1.progressProperty(), task2.progressProperty());
```

If you can easily estimate or compute the relative times each task will take, you can weight the progress of each task accordingly, instead of simply averaging them as in the code above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that doesn't work for me. If I am doing as you propose, the progressBar will display a blue bar from 50% and run over 100% to restart when changing directory at 60% approximately... :(

Comment: @cy8el1us Ah, ok, I didn't read your original code well enough. Why are you repeatedly resetting the progress to zero in the second task? Typically, how many files are you iterating over in total here?

Comment: No pb! I reduced the code and using only one task now. But now, when the task access to the method which read files, access seems to be without synchronization so the result is a mix of every files. Do you have an idea on how to fix this? see my edit

Comment: @cy8el1us Now surely the maximum value for the progress is wrong.